# what operating system concepts should every programmer be aware of?

Tags: operating-system

I am compiling various lists of competencies that self taught programmers must have.

Among all subjects, Operating Systems is the trickiest one, because creating even a toy operating system is a rather non-trivial task. However, at the same time an application developer (who may not have formally learned CS) must at least be aware of and hopefully should have implemented some key concepts to appreciate how an OS works, and to be a better developer.

I have a few specific questions:

- What key concepts of operating systems are important for a self taught programmer to understand so they can be better software developers (albeit working on regular application development)?
- Is it even remotely possible to learn such a subject in byte sized practical pieces ? (Even a subject like compiler construction can be learned in a hands on way, at a rather low level of complexity)

Comment: Why is this question not constructive ? If appropriate knowledge of Operating Systems can help a person be a better developer, then the answer should be of interest to many developers and organizations who want their developers to be better. This is very similar to many questions of the type "What should every developer know about X"

Comment: From [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. [...] If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." Still, while your question does not fit the FAQ, I don't believe it is not constructuve; it _might_ be argued to be off-topic, but it actuall fits the topic of programming quite well. The only real problem I see is that you haven't mentioned results of your own research about the question.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest reading **Andrew S. Tanenbaum** ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum ) book on **Modern Operating Systems** (ISBN 978-0-13-600663-3) as everything is there.

However from the book index we can identify the minimum key topics:

- Processes
- Memory management
- File systems
- Input/output

And the easiest way to start playing with this topics will be to download **MINIX**:

http://www.minix3.org/

and study the code. Older versions of this operating system might be easier to understand.

Another useful resource is **Mike Saunders** *How to write a simple operating system* that  shows you how to write and build your first operating system in x86 assembly language:

http://mikeos.sourceforge.net/write-your-own-os.html

Comment: above link to write your own os is not working.Can you provide any other link?

Comment: @princess I am not sure if this is what luigif was referring to, but I believe [this](http://mikeos.sourceforge.net/write-your-own-os.html) is the new link to the broken link in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @abdul, I've corrected the broken link

Answer (score 5):

Every OS designer must understand the concepts behind [Multics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multics).   One of the most brilliant ideas is the notion of of a vast virtual memory partioned into directly readable and writable segments with full protections, and multiprocessor support to boot; with 64 bit pointers, we have enough bits to address everything on the planet directly.    These ideas are from the 1960s yet timeless IMHO.

The apparent loss of such knowledge got us "Eunuchs" now instantiated as Unix then Linux and an equally poor design from Microsoft, both of which organize the world as a flat process space and files.  Those who don't know history are doomed to doing something dumber.

Do anything you can to get a copy of Organick's book on Multics, and *read it*, cover to cover.   (Elliott I. Organick, The Multics System: An Examination of Its Structure).

The wikipedia site has some good information; Corbato's papers are great.

Comment: Organick's book is interesting on several levels. Besides the technical angle, reading how he carefully explained some of the nowadays obvious concepts, in 1972, is voluptuous. (Unfortunately a lot of other concepts from the book have been shockingly ignored in systems coming later on...)

Answer (score 3):

I believe it depends on the type of application you are developing and the OS platform you are developing for. For example if you are developing a website you don't need to know too much about the OS. In this example you need to know more about your webserver. There are different things you need to know when you are working on Windows, Linux or Android or some embedded system or sometimes you need to know nothing beyond what your API provides. In general it is always good for a developer or CS person to know following.

1. What lies in the responsibility of application, toolchain and then OS.
2. Inter process communication and different IPC mechanism the OS system calls provides.

OS is quite an interesting subject but mostly consist of theory but this theory comes to action when you working on embedded systems. On average for desktop applications you don't see where all that theory fits in.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, operating system concepts that a good programmer should be aware of.
practically speaking.  Unless you are concerned about performance.  If you are writing in a cross os language. None.

If you *care* about performance.

1. The cost of user/system transitions

   How the os handles locking/threads/deadlocks and how to best use them.

   Virtual Memory/Paging/thrashing and the cost thereof.

   Memory allocation, how the os does it, and how you should take advantage of that to when A, use the OS allocator ( see 1) and when to allocate from the os and sub allocate.

   As earlier put, process creation/ and inter process communication.

   How the os writes/reads to disk by default to read/write optimally ( see why databases use B-trees)

   Bonus, sub-os, what cache size and cache lines can mean to you in terms of performance.

but generally it would boil down to what does the OS provide you that isn't generic, and what and why does it cost, and what will cost too much ( too much cpu, too much disk usage, too much io, too much network ect).

Answer (score 2):

Well that depends on the need of the developer like:-

**Point.**

Applications such as web browsers and email tools are
performing an increasingly important role inmodern desktop computer
systems. To fulfill this role, they should be incorporated as part of the
operating system. By doing so, they can provide better performance
and better integration with the rest of the system. In addition, these
important applications can have the same look-and-feel as the operating
system software.

**Counterpoint.**

The fundamental role of the operating system is to manage
system resources such as the CPU, memory, I/O devices, etc. In addition,
it’s role is to run software applications such as web browsers and
email applications. By incorporating such applications into the operating
system, we burden the operating system with additional functionality.
Such a burdenmay result in the operating system performing a less-thansatisfactory
job at managing system resources. In addition, we increase
the size of the operating system thereby increasing the likelihood of
system crashes and security violations.

[image]

Also there are many other important points which one must understand to get a better grip of Operating System like  Multithreading, Multitasking, Virtual Memory, Demand Paging, Memory Management, Processor Management, and more.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20every%20programmer%20should%20know%20about%20memory).  (Not completely OS, but all of it is useful information.  And chapter 4 covers virtual memory, which is the first thing that came to mind reading your question.)

To learn the rest piecemeal, pick any system call and learn exactly what it does.  This will often mean learning about the kernel objects it manipulates.

Of course, the details will differ from OS to OS...  But so does the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put:

Threads and Processes.

Kernel space/threads vs user space/threads (probably some kernel level programming)

Followed by the very fundamental concepts of process deadlocks.

And thereafter monitors vs semaphores vs mutex

How Memory works and talks to process and devices.

Answer (score 0):

Every self-taught programmer and computer scientist alike should know the OSI model and know it well. It helps to identify where a problem could lie and who to contact if there are problems. The scope is defined here and many issues could be filtered out here. 
This is because there is just too much in an operating system to simply learn it all. As a web developer I usually work in the application level when an issue ever goes out of this scope I know when i need help. Also many people simply do not care about certain components they want to create thing as quickly as possible. The OSI model is a place where someone can find their computer hot spot. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Comment: Welcome to P.SE - I'm not sure I'd agree with the opening sentence, because (for many of us dealing with small micros on embedded systems) there is often just no need (nor the resources) to use the OSI model.  However, in the networking and desktop world, where resources are (always) in surplus, then yes, I agree.